# How to run a subprocess in the background python

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm writing an application in python that initiates a JVM in java by calling a shell script using a python subprocess. However, my problem is that the correct way I have it written, the JVM starts and blocks the rest of the processes that happen after it. I need the JVM to run while I'm calling another function, and I need to stop the JVM after the process has finished running.

Python code:

```
process = subprocess.Popen('runJVM.sh', shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
process.wait()

r = Recommender()
r.load()
assert len(sys.argv) > 1, '%d arguments supplied, one needed' %(len(sys.argv)-1)
print "recommendations" + str(r.get_users_recommendation(sys.argv[1:]))

....
def get_users_recommendation(self, user_list):
    j_id_list = ListConverter().convert(class_list, self.gateway._gateway_client)
    recs = self.gateway.entry_point.recommend(j_id_list)
    return recs
```

Where:

```
 from py4j.java_gateway import JavaGateway
 self.gateway = JavaGateway()
```

I can't get the `get_user_recommendations` to run because the JVM server is blocking the process. How do I not make it block the rest of the Python script and then kill it once the python methods have finished running and returned a value? Much thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`process.wait()` is blocking your process. Remove that line and the rest of the code will run.
Then you can make it end by calling `Popen.terminate()`

Popen is invoking *CreateProcess*, that means the OS launches a new process and returns the PID to be stored on your *process* variable.

If you use `process.wait()`, then your code will wait until the recently created process ends (it never ends in this case unless you terminate it externally).

If you do not call `process.wait()`, your code will continue to execute. But you still have control over the other process and you can do things like `process.terminate()` or even `process.kill()` if necessary.

Comment: `CreateProcess` is used on Windows. Popen calls [`execv(3)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html) on POSIX systems.